# Full HD video playback acceleration with mplayer on Ubuntu Lucid

Tags: linux, video, ubuntu-10.04, playback, acceleration

I know that for an NVidia card I can `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current mplayer`, reboot, and then use `mplayer -vo vdpau -vc ffmpeg12vdpau,ffwmv3vdpau,ffvc1vdpau,ffh264vdpau FILE.mkv` to get accelerated video playback of H.264 and other codecs, so even full HD videos can be played back with only little CPU. (And there are many other options, e.g. XBMC also supports VDPAU.)

But how do I get accelerated video playback if I have a recent ATI or Intel video card on Ubuntu Lucid? How do I figure out if my video card has acceleration built in? The solution has to work with [mplayer](http://mplayerhq.hu/) or [mplayer2](http://mplayer2.org/). It's OK for me to recompile mplayer(2), but I'd prefer installing both the kernel and the X.org X server from a binary package repository.

Comment: mplayer2 doesn't support VA-API yet: http://devel.mplayer2.org/ticket/17

Comment: Intel's video driver supports accelerated video decoding (http://intellinuxgraphics.org/h264.html) with a fork of mplayer (https://gitorious.org/vaapi/mplayer) The minimum Linux kernel version seems to be 3.2.x, which is not available for Ubuntu Lucid.